# Database column undefined when dumped individually - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query that returns `DATE - ID - NAME - NOTE - TIME` when I dump it by using `<cfdump var="#q_data#">`

I am trying to dump only the value `DATE` by using `<cfdump var="q_data.date">` but it returns `Element DATE is undefined in DATA.`

This is my code:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#directory#\#q_oBandDirectory.name#" query="q_data" headerrow="1"  excludeHeaderRow = "true"   columns = "1-5"  >

<cfdump var="#q_data.date#"> <-- Does not work
<cfdump var="#q_data.ID#"> <--- Works as it should
<cfdump var="#q_data.NAME#"> <--- Works as it should
```

Is there anything special that I have to do in this situation because the query is created from a spread sheet tag?

Comment: I didn't think "date" was a reserved word when used as a column name. Try `<cfdump var="#q_data['date'][1]#">` to see if that grabs it.

Comment: I fixed it. I had a space after "DATE" in the damn spreadsheet!

Comment: Wow, that could have taken all day to find. :o)

Comment: It actually did... I changed my code around a million times and read about a dozen forums before posting in here...